# PDO fetch class with foreign key

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have the classes:

```
class Order {
    private $order_id;
    private $product;
    private $quantity;
}

class Product {
    private $product_id;
    private $name;
    private $price;
}
```

I also have those MySql tables:

```
orders:
+----------+------------------+----------+
| order_id |     product      | quantity |
+----------+------------------+----------+
| INTEGER  | INT(FOREIGN KEY) | INTEGER  |
+----------+------------------+----------+

products:
+------------+---------+---------+
| product_id |   name  |  price  |
+------------+---------+---------+
|   INTEGER  | VARCHAR | INTEGER |
+------------+---------+---------+
```

`orders.product` is a foreign key associated with `product.product_id`.

I would like to fetch, using PDO, an order with id 123 from orders table and automatically store the result in an `Order` class. I know there is `PDO::fetchObject` and `PDO::FETCH_CLASS`, the problem is they don't work recursively.

I know I have the easy solution of fetching the `order_id` and `quantity` columns in one query, and then fetching the product fields in a second query.
Is there a way to achieve this in one query (using JOIN)?

Comment: What do you mean by *the problem is they don't work recursively* ?

Comment: @Mikey The result I want is an Order object, with product field pointing to a Procut object, with both object's fields having the fetched values.

Comment: I am pretty sure there is no "easy" way to do that. You have to code that logic yourself. Solution 1 seems the best choice IMO using 2 `fetchObject()` and then setting the order's product. Solution 2 might work with a `fetchObject()` but you would have some ugly logic somewhere to rebuild the order's product.

Answer (score 1):

You can do bit magic in your `Order` class, like:

```
$dbh = new PDO(...);

class Order {
    private $order_id;
    private $product_id;
    // IMPORTANT!
    // If class have `product` property - setter won't be called.
    // private $product;
    private $quantity;

    // PDO call this method only in case
    // class doesn't have property with same name like column in db.
    public function __set($name, $value) {
        // If property is product - call setProduct.
        if ($name === 'product') {
            $this->setProduct($value);
        }
    }

    public function setProduct($productId)
    {
        /** \PDO IMPORTANT global var here just for example, use better design. */
        global $dbh;
        $s = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_id = :pId');
        $s->bindParam(':pId', $productId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $s->execute();
        $this->product = $s->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, Product::class);
    }
}

$s = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM orders WHERE order_id = :oId');
$s->bindValue(':oId', 123, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$s->execute();
$result = $s->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, Order::class);
```

Comment: The problem is that I don't want to send 2 queries to the DB, because I can fetch this information using one query. :/

Comment: Added another answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's extension to my previous answer as another option:

Order:

```
class Order {
    private $order_id;
    private $product_id;
    private $quantity;

    public function __set($name, $value) {
        if ($this->product === null) {
            $this->product = new Product();
        }
        switch ($name) {
            case 'productId':
                 $this->product->setProductId($value);
                break;
            case 'productName':
                 $this->product->setName($value);
                break;
            case 'productPrice':
                 $this->product->setPrice($value);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Product:

```
class Product {
    private $product_id;
    private $name;
    private $price;

    public function setProductId($product_id)
    {
        $this->product_id = $product_id;
    }

    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function setPrice($price)
    {
        $this->price = $price;
    }
}
```

Ussage:

```
$dbh = new PDO(...);
$s = $dbh->prepare('
    SELECT o.*, p.product_id productId, p.name productName, p.price productPrice
    FROM orders o
    JOIN products p ON o.product = p.product_id
    WHERE order_id = :oId
');
$s->bindValue(':oId', 123, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$s->execute();
$result = $s->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, Order::class);
```